# Google Script: Write folder path to google sheets in one cell instead of one row and limit folder path

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to add data from folders to a google sheet using google sheets. I would like to have the full folder path in one cell. At the moment I am getting the folder path in one column but not in one row.
Like this:

Folder 1

Subfolder 2

SubSubfolder 3

Instead of:

Folder 1 (next cell) Subfolder 1 (next cell) Subsubfolder 1

Folder 1 (next cell) Subfolder 2 (next cell) Subsubfolder 1

Another issue i have been facing is that I would like to limit the depth of the folder path to 3 , how can I integrate that in the loop?
I tried using the && operator but that didn't do the trick as the loop goes on and starts counting from a different folder.

Help is highly appreciated :)

Thank you in advance.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var topFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID");
  var topPath = "/";
  sheet.appendRow(["Extracted Folder", "Industry", "Client", "Projectname","Size of Folder", "Link to Folder", "Date Created", "Owner"])

  iterateSubFolders(topFolder, topPath)
}

function iterateSubFolders(callingFolder, callingPath, sheet) {

  var callingFolderName = callingFolder.getName();
  var callingFolderFullPath = callingPath + callingFolderName + "/";
  Logger.log(callingFolderFullPath);
     
  addRowToSheetForFolder(callingFolder)
  n=0
  var childSubFolders = callingFolder.getFolders();
  while ((childSubFolders.hasNext()) && (n < 3) ) {
      var nextSubFolder = childSubFolders.next();
      iterateSubFolders(nextSubFolder, callingFolderFullPath);
      n=n+1
  }
  return callingFolderFullPath;
    //This should only return the folder path with the depth = 3
    //The full folder path should appear in the google sheets in one row
}

function addRowToSheetForFolder(folder) {
  var FolderBanking = DriveApp.getFolderById("13C4cnxnzNP_HMItTiS5PpuyQgWovUuF_");
  data = [
             
             //FolderBanking, //Parent folder
             folder.getName().toString(),
             "move industry here",
             "move client to here",
             "move project name to here",
             folder.getSize(),
             folder.getUrl(),
             folder.getDateCreated(),
             //folder.getOwner().getName(), geht nur für MyDrive
             "manuell pflegen",
             folder.getDescription(),
         ];
  Logger.log("Writing row to sheet");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(data);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to accomplish two things:

- Have the full folder path for the corresponding folder in a single cell (column `A`) instead of the name of the nested folder.
- Limit the folder search to 3 levels, so folders further down the hierarchy are not retrieved.

If that's correct, you can do the following.

### Folder path in one cell:

Allow `addRowToSheetForFolder` to accept a second parameter corresponding to the folder path, which you have previously retrieved, and append that to the sheet.

```
addRowToSheetForFolder(callingFolder, callingFolderFullPath);
```

### Limit depth to 3:

Allow `iterateSubFolders` to accept a `depth` parameter, set it to `3` when calling it in `myFunction`, set it to `depth - 1` when calling it inside the `while` loop, and make the loop dependent on `depth`:

```
iterateSubFolders(nextSubFolder, callingFolderFullPath, depth - 1);
```

#### Sample output:

[image]

#### Code snippet:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var topFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID");
  var topPath = "/";
  sheet.appendRow(["Extracted Folder", "Industry", "Client", "Projectname","Size of Folder", "Link to Folder", "Date Created", "Owner"])
  iterateSubFolders(topFolder, topPath, 3)
}

function iterateSubFolders(callingFolder, callingPath, depth) {
  var callingFolderName = callingFolder.getName();
  var callingFolderFullPath = callingPath + callingFolderName + "/";
  addRowToSheetForFolder(callingFolder, callingFolderFullPath);
  n=0;
  var childSubFolders = callingFolder.getFolders();
  while ((childSubFolders.hasNext()) && (n < depth) ) {
      var nextSubFolder = childSubFolders.next();
      iterateSubFolders(nextSubFolder, callingFolderFullPath, depth - 1);
  }
  return callingFolderFullPath;
}

function addRowToSheetForFolder(folder, fullFolderPath) {
  data = [
             fullFolderPath,
             "move industry here",
             "move client to here",
             "move project name to here",
             folder.getSize(),
             folder.getUrl(),
             folder.getDateCreated(),
             "manuell pflegen",
             folder.getDescription()
         ];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(data);
}
```

#### Update:

If you want to append the data to different cells from the same row, just use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) when appending the data to the sheet:

```
data = [...fullFolderPath.split("/"), "move industry here", ...];
```

Also, change top path to an empty string if you don't want to skip column A:

```
var topPath = "";
```

Comment: Is it also possible to have the folder path in the same row but in different cells per folder?
Like this:  
Folder 1 is in 1A
Folder 2 is in 1B
Folder 3 is in 1C

Comment: @Chiara Sure, just remove `n=n+1` from the `while` loop. There's no reason for that line and it limits what can be retrieved in a certain folder (I edited my answer with this change).

Comment: @Chiara Also added an `Updated` section at the bottom of my answer explaining how to append the path to different cells.

Comment: if I remove the `n=n+1` I no longer am able to limit the folder depth to 3, right?

Comment: @lamblichus 
when i split the folder path I get values like this: [Ljava.lang.Object;@1e22c478

Comment: @Chiara That shouldn't be the case, since the `depth` keeps getting reduced with each recursion. So three levels down, it will be 0 and the code won't enter the while loop. `n=n+1` does nothing here.

Comment: @Chiara `when i split the folder path I get values like this: [Ljava.lang.Object;@1e22c478 ` This shouldn't be the case if `callingFolderFullPath` is a string. Also I cannot reproduce this, I'm getting the expected results. Are you using the code I provided?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234072/discussion-between-chiara-and-iamblichus).